# Shifting SVG symbol to specific point in QGIS

Tags: qgis, style, svg, anchor-point

Is it possible in QGIS to make a particular point of a custom `.svg`-symbol coincide with the layer point position? i.e referring to the image: I would like to make the beginning of the symbol line coincide with the geographical position of the point in the layer (cross):

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the beginning of the line starts in the middle of the .svg file, the beginning of the symbol will be where your point is positioned.

I added two photos to make it clear. First one is the .svg file, second is in QGIS:

[image]

[image]

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, (i.e. in inkscape) should I set a page of appropriate size and move the symbol so that the beginning of the line coincides with the center of the page?

Comment: Yes exactly. You can use auxiliary lines (hope that's the correct name, since I do not use Inkscape in English) to find the middle.

Comment: I've tried setting document page format as square (as shown in the image of your example) in inkscape and it seems to work well. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, QGIS is not that superpowerful in the sense of visualization and symbolization.

However, in your case, I can suggest `Layer Properties > Style > SVG Marker > Anchor point`

There is a possibility to edit the anchor point with custom expression, which will include `"FIELD_x"` and `"FIELD_Y"` accordingly.

Furthermore, you can play with `Offset X,Y`.
But be careful when working with metric dimensions, since the changes that you apply to the SVG marker offset in QGIS main window will differ from the visual part in Print Composer.

And as @J.R mentioned, it is better to work with map units.

Comment: I suggest to set all symbology unit to map unit, that way the size and offset of symbol won't need to be adjusted each time the scale change

Comment: (Yes i'm working with map units) You say:"There is a possibility to edit the anchor point with custom expression, which will include [FIELD_x] and [FIELD_Y] accordingly.", are anchor point setting (low, center, high, left,, center, right) related to the geometry/dimensions of SVG marker?